# How to stack arrays in repa (Haskell)

Tags: arrays, haskell, repa

Suppose there are two 1-D arrays of the same length:

```
let x = fromListUnboxed (ix1 4) [1, 2, 3, 4]
let y = fromListUnboxed (ix1 4) [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Now I would like to stack these two arrays into one 2-D array so that these arrays form the rows. How can I do it in repa?

Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent of numpy's `row_stack`:

```py
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> np.row_stack((x, y))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

**Note.** The two arrays, `x` and `y`, come from outside, i.e. I cannot create the 2-D array from scratch.

Comment: I think all you need is to `reshape` the `x` and `y` arrays to be 2D and then `append` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the initial comment, all you need is to `reshape` then `append` (both in [Data.Array.Repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.1/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html).

```
ghci> let x' = reshape (ix2 4 1) x
ghci> let y' = reshape (ix2 4 1) y
ghci> z <- computeP $ x' `append` y' :: IO (Array U DIM2 Int)
ghci> z
AUnboxed ((Z :. 4) :. 2) [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
```

As for pretty-printing, `repa` isn't very good (likely because there is no good pretty printing for higher dimensions). Here is a one-line hack to display `z`

```
ghci> putStr $ unlines [ unwords [ show $ z ! ix2 i j  |  i<-[0..3] ] | j<-[0..1] ]
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Just out of curiosity - is it possible to control in which dimension are the arrays appended? Or is it only in the last one?

Comment: @zegkljan I don't think there is a slick general approach for that - you'd have to change the shape, append, then change the shape back. For two dimensions you can use `transpose`, but otherwise I think you'd go with `backpermute`. Bear in mind that even `col_stack` for numpy only works for 1D arguments too - there just is no simple way to generalize both `row_stack` and `col_stack` to N dimensions.